# How to parse a string "(2 -59.0)"?

Tags: c++

How can I parse a string like `"(x y)"` (example: `"(2 -59.0)"`, `(11 1)`) into a integer `x` and a float `y`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular: "sum up your entire question in one sentence".

Comment: Is your question: "How can I parse the string `"(x y)"` where x and y are numeric (integer or floats)?"

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann "X" - is int; "Y" - float.

Comment: Have you searched the plethora of related questions:  [StackOverflow C++ read file parse?](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+parse&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Please edit your question with your attempt at parsing.  Hint:  Use `getline` to read the string and `std::istringstream` to extract the data.  Also, review the `find` methods of `std::string`.

Comment: this question is way too broad as written, you could use anything from `scanf` to hand-rolled parsing using C++ streams, to `boost::spirit::qi` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a primarily C background I'm particularly fond of [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) particularly when the data is as well formed as described in your question. However, there are several other ways that you could do this. If you want a purely C++ implementation I suggest you look at the [`<sstream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/) header.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int x;
    float y;

    std::string str = "(2 -59.0)";

    sscanf(str.c_str(), "(%d %f)", &x, &y);

    std::cout << "(" << x << " " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

This produces

```
$ ./a.out
(2 -59)
```